# Using lxml to add a string as a sub element

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have an lxml element with children built like this:

```
xml = etree.Element('presentation')
format_xml = etree.SubElement(xml, 'format')
content_xml = etree.SubElement(xml, 'slides')
```

I then have several strings that I would like it iterate over and add each as child element to slides. Each string will be something like this:

```
<slide1>
    <title>My Presentation</title>
    <subtitle>A sample presentation</subtitle>
    <phrase>Some sample text
        <subphrase>Some more text</subphrase>
    </phrase>
</slide1>
```

How can I append these strings as children to the slides element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just append:

```
import lxml.etree as etree

xml = etree.Element('presentation')
format_xml = etree.SubElement(xml, 'format')
content_xml = etree.SubElement(xml, 'slides')
new = """<slide1>
    <title>My Presentation</title>
    <subtitle>A sample presentation</subtitle>
    <phrase>Some sample text
        <subphrase>Some more text</subphrase>
    </phrase>
</slide1>"""


content_xml.append(etree.fromstring(new))


print(etree.tostring(xml,pretty_print=1))
```

Which will give you:

```
<presentation>
  <format/>
  <slides>
    <slide1>
    <title>My Presentation</title>
    <subtitle>A sample presentation</subtitle>
    <phrase>Some sample text
        <subphrase>Some more text</subphrase>
    </phrase>
</slide1>
  </slides>
</presentation>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`fromstring()`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-fromstring-function) function would load an XML string directly into an `Element` instance which you can append:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

slide = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
content_xml.append(slide)
```